# GCP: Creating private postgre instance in a specific subnet

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, vpc-peering

I want to create a private postgresql instance that is pointing to a specific subnet in my VPC. I have 2 resources:

```
resource "google_compute_global_address" "private_ip_address_some_name" {
  name          = "private-ip-address-some-name"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = 16
  network       = module.vpc.vpc.id
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "some_other_name" {
  network                 = module.vpc.vpc.id
  service                 = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.private_ip_address_some_name.name]
}
```

And I do understand that this would create the IP in my VPC, but I wish the postgres instance to be created inside a specific subnet inside my VPC.

The VPC kind of looks like this:

```
dev-01 : {
  vpc_cidr = "x.x.x.x/16"
  subnets = {
    "subnet-a" : ["10.2.1.0/24", "secondary_ip_range/20", "x.x.x.x/20"],
    "subnet-b" : ["10.2.2.0/24", "secondary_ip_range/20", "x.x.x.x/20"],

  }
```

And the ip_configuration on my postgresql module looks like this:

```
  ip_configuration = {
    ipv4_enabled       = true                                # Disable public IP
    private_network    = module.vpc.vpc.id                   
    allocated_ip_range = var.network_map[local.env].vpc_cidr 
    require_ssl        = true                               
    authorized_networks = [
      {
        name  = "vpc"
        value = "10.2.1.0/24"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have the subnet configured as an output:

```
output "subnet-a" {
  value = google_compute_subnetwork.db_a
}
```

I have tried to reference it like so:

> ```
> private_network    = module.vpc.subnet-a.id
> ```

but without any luck.

I am kind of lost on this as every attempt I tried to point towards a subnet has failed and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "but without any luck" Please replace this with an error message or a description of actual versus expected behavior so that we can assist.

Comment: I have tried many possible solutions. The one that I specified in my post returns this error:
```│ Error: "settings.0.ip_configuration.0.private_network" ("projects/project/regions/europe/subnetworks/subnet-a") doesn't match regexp "^(?:http(?:s)?://.+/)?projects/((?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\\.)*(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)))/global/networks/((?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?))$"
│ 
│   with module.postgre_db_pj_int.google_sql_database_instance.default,
│   on .terraform/modules/postgre_db/modules/postgresql/main.tf```

Comment: `private_network` expects the id of a subnet, not a subnet (as suggested by the error, the regex to match must contains `global/networks`), [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance#private_network).

Answer (score 0):

`private_network` expects the id of a subnet, not a subnet (as suggested by the error, the regex to match must contains `global/networks`), [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance#private_network).

Instead, you are passing it the id of a subnetwork, thus the error.